# rsyslog EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive can't work in omfwd module?

Tags: linux, logging, syslog

I'm using rsyslog omfwd for log transfer and collect, the "\t" has been changed to "#011" by rsyslog. I tried to use "$EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive off" and saw the omfile result of my frontend server is right, BUT the forward server can't process logline anymore(I can saw the NIC traffic in-flow keep still but out-flow decrease to 0).

I have put "$EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive off" both in centre server rsyslog.conf and restart it, no changes.